# WebdriverIO - How to accept location prompt from Chrome? (chromedriver)

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I am currently working on automating tests for a website that, when launched in incognito mode, asks user for their location. ( Similar to https://www.where-am-i.co/ ). However while I managed to configure for location to be denied, I am unable to configure it to be automatically accepted on each browser launch.

In wdio.conf.js under capabilities I put

```
        "goog:chromeOptions": {
            args: [
                "--incognito"
            ],
            prefs: {
                'profile': {
                 'default_content_setting_values': {
                    'geolocation': 1
                  }
                }
              },
        }
}],
```

Setting `'geolocation': 1` is supposed to confirm location every time but it does not work. However if geolocation is set to 2, it does work and location prompt gets denied.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this in your 'goog:chromeOptions':

```
 'goog:chromeOptions': {
        prefs: {
            'profile.managed_default_content_settings.popups' : 1,
            'profile.managed_default_content_settings.notifications' : 1,
        }
    },
```